# which is the best way to call send() for a smartcontract method?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm developing a new dapp and I'm wondering with current Ethereum state of network, which are correct parameters to send along with web3, i.e.

`myconytact.methods.myfunction(<params>).send({from:address,?????})`

my problem is gas, gas limit and so on. I should use estimateGas? and the put gas:gas in the object passed in send()?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you never need to put in gas or gas limit, as those are set by the user in his or her wallet when confirming the transaction.